# Android, Gradle and duplicate files error during packaging

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, jsonschema

I want to use the json-schema-validator in my Android project like this:

`dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:2.1.8'
}`

Unfortunately Gradle stops packaging due to this file duplicate error:

`Path in archive: draftv3/schema
  Origin 1: /Users/andrej/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator/2.1.8/4c2a5be8ce86c2338561a651d7d22fb4c4a8763d/json-schema-validator-2.1.8.jar
  Origin 2: /Users/andrej/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.fge/json-schema-core/1.1.9/4ead9ba3fb3bde69d93f738042d12a9e60e41645/json-schema-core-1.1.9.jar`

I know I can ignore the file like this:

`packagingOptions {
   exclude 'draftv3/schema'
}`

But the file is used by json-schema-validator and json-validator-core, so it is required in the resulting APK.

How can I force Gradle to proceed packaging while keeping one of the two versions of this file (they are equal)?

Thanks,
Andrej

Answer (score 2):

By explicitly mentioning the draftv/schema files in the build.graddle file we can resolve this issue.

```
    android {

    ...

        packagingOptions {

            ...

            pickFirst 'draftv3/schema'
            pickFirst 'draftv4/schema'

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For others, here a quick workaround until Gradle will add packaging options with proper duplicate strategies:

`android.applicationVariants.all { variant->
    variant.assemble.doFirst {
        exec {
            executable "sh"
            args "-c", "find ~/.gradle/caches/ -iname 'json-schema-validator*.jar' -exec zip -d '{}' 'draftv3/schema' \\;"
            args "-c", "find ~/.gradle/caches/ -iname 'json-schema-validator*.jar' -exec zip -d '{}' 'draftv4/schema' \\;"
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to only exclude `draftv3/schema` from your dependency:

```
dependencies {
   compile('com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:2.1.8') {
       exclude 'draftv3/schema'
   }
}
```

Comment: This will exclude the file from being packaged. But the file is used by json-schema-validator and json-validator-core, so it is required in the resulting APK.

Comment: How are you adding the json-validator-core dependency?

Comment: The json-validator-core is automaticaly added by "dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:2.1.8'
}"