# How to validate JSON in Gradle build

Tags: json, validation, gradle

I have a Gradle build where a large JSON configuration is bundled into a package for later upload onto a server. Sometimes when changes are made to the file, the file is not valid any more and thus fails to upload on the server.

I would like to find this earlier by adding a validate-step in the Gradle build.

When looking around I could not find a documented way to do this, I saw the project [gradle-json-validator](https://github.com/alenkacz/gradle-json-validator) which looks promising, but there is no documentation whatsoever, so I am not sure how this can be used...

Any hint on gradle-json-validator or any other way to validate a JSON file as part of the Gradle build steps?

Comment: Possibly related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228647/android-gradle-and-duplicate-files-error-during-packaging

Comment: Yeah, but contains lots of stuff about Android building, which I am not that inclined to look at. I am in contact with the author of gradle-json-validator and will update this question when the documentation is in a state to make it useable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From source, it would seem, the usage would be:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'cz.alenkacz.gradle:json-validator:0.9.9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'cz.alenkacz.gradle.jsonvalidator'
```

The plugin doesn't seem to have an extension to do configuration. But seems to use `jsonSchema` and `targetJsonFile` as input schema and file-to-validate. I would try setting them at the root level of `build.gradle`

```
validateJson.jsonSchema = new File('/path/to/schema')
validateJson.targetJsonFile = new File('/path/to/jsonFile')
```

and the task to run is:

```
gradle validateJson
```

Comment: Hm, did not work this way, for "targetJsonFile = File('/path/to/jsonFile')", I get "Could not find method File()". For "targetJsonFile = 'path/to/jsonFile'", I get "No such property: targetJsonFile for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated"

Comment: Thanks, this now basically works, although now the JSON Schema fails to parse, but that is likely another question...

Answer (score 3):

I have improved the readme file in the repository with proper usage example.

Hope that helps. https://github.com/alenkacz/gradle-json-validator